# Can this question be rephrased to be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope, specific-question

> [What are common places to try for alternatives to commercially available seeds?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/where-can-i-order-a-larger-variety-of-vegetable-seeds)

Would editing to remove the "Is there a place I can go online?" make this question not fall afoul of the "shopping" ban?

Comment: I've reworded and reopened the question with a focus along what you suggested. Please edit it further if you think it can be improved. Since this meta post was about this specific question, I'm marking it status-completed and closing it as localized (in time). **Note to all:**  I'd appreciate if all discussion on the topic of such questions were done on [this broader](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/285/teaching-a-man-to-fish-garden-and-shop) question.

Answer (score 2):

I figured I'd give it a crack, the gist of the question is what kind of a place should I look.  The answer may be obvious now, "anywhere but Walmart" but at least it's answerable.

Answer (score 1):

I certainly would've edited if I really thought it could be reworded as a non-shopping question. At the heart of it, it really is a *"Who sells these seeds?"* question. However, I do like [your suggestion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/why-is-it-off-topic-to-ask-for-a-source-for-a-plant/282#282) to change the focus to teach people *where* to look for possible resources rather than doing the googling/searching for them and posting the link. I've outlined a few thoughts and some possible policy changes on this issue in [this meta post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/teaching-a-man-to-fish-garden-and-shop). Seeing how the discussion goes, I'd be more than happy to reopen it with a renewed focus as you've suggested.

Comment: Actually, at the heart of my question is 'Where can I get a larger variety of seed types' because Australia is dominated by corporate style building and gardening centres that only sell the same brand and same limited variety. So if someone could help to reword the question to something acceptable I would be grateful!